# Serialize form - input's with same name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have the followin code :

```
<form id="sendObj">
        <table class="no-border hover list">
          <tbody class="no-border-y">';
            while($pendingTransfers = mysql_fetch_assoc($getPending)){
                $id = $pendingTransfers['id'];
                echo '
            <tr class="items">
              <td style="width: 10%;"><span class="label label-primary">'.$counter++.'</span></td>
              <td class="text-left"><p>'.$pendingTransfers['NumarInventar'].'</p></td>
              <td class="text-left"><p><strong>'.$pendingTransfers['DenumireArticol'].'</strong></p></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$pendingTransfers['id'].'" />
                <td class="text-center"><input type="hidden" name="depID" class="getDep" data-placeholder="Selecteaza destinatie" />  <i style="color:red" title="Sterge din lista" onclick="deleteLista('.$pendingTransfers['id'].');" class="text-right fa fa-times-circle fa-lg"></i></td>
            </tr>';}
                echo '
           </tbody>
        </table>
            </form>     
<div class="text-center"><button id="BtnSendObj" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check color-inverse fa-lg"></i> Finish transfers</button></div>
```

The above code brings the inserted DB id for each record and on each row in the above table an select option from wich the user can chose some value. When user finishes , he will press the button " Finish transfers" and all the inputs must be serialized. The problem is that i have multiple inputs with same name and i cannot group them all as i can use them later in PHP. For exemple i can have 5 row's on each row 1 of each input . So the result will **id=1 DepId=3456 , id =2 DepId = 5432** and so on.

```
$('#BtnSendObj').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data;
    var a = $('#sendObj').serializeArray();

    $.each(a, function () {
    var depID = $('input[name=depDestinatie]').serializeArray();
    var id = $('input[name=id]').serializeArray();

     data =[{"id":id, "depID":depID}];  
    }); 

    //The above will output something like :
    // [Object]0: Object
    //depId: Array[4]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object...
    // id: Array[4]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object

    // Like this i cannot handle them togerther in PHP.
    // I think it should look like an array of objects so like this i would   //be able to acces them easly , i think that both id's should be in same object //, but this is were i dont know how to proceed.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'subpages/data/transferObjects.php',
        data: {data: data},
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log('AJAX SUCCESS');
            console.log(data);
        }, 
        complete : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

        }
});
});
```

Here i handle the ajax post.

What i want to achieve it's to send the data to a php file where i will update DB with the values from the form.

The php files looks like this :

```
//some connection 
        if(isset($_POST['data']))
    {
    $updateObjects = mysql_query("UPDATE transactions SET IDDepartamentDestinatie = '$_POST['depID'] WHERE id = '{$_POST['id']}'");

    }
```

But like this it will only update the last record from the form as i dont loop through all inputs.

If someone has some idee how can i do this , i've tried all examples found about serializeArray or serialize, but didnt worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a case like this there is another possibility - name those inputs with `[]` appended to the name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$pendingTransfers['id'].'" />
<input type="hidden" name="depID[]" class="getDep" data-placeholder="Selecteaza destinatie" />
```

Then in your `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['depId']` you will automatically have arrays. So without additional hustle you just put it as data in your ajax function like this:

```
data: $.param($('#sendObj').serializeArray())
```

In PHP you take advantage from the fact that the keys in both arrays are the same for corresponding value pairs:

```
if(isset($_POST['depID'])){
    foreach($_POST['depID']) as $k => $v){
        mysql_query("UPDATE transactions SET IDDepartamentDestinatie = '$v' WHERE id = '{$_POST['id'][$k]}'");
    }
}
```

Also bear in mind that $_POST values should be sanitized with mysql_real_escape_string, better yet, use PDO for mysql handling.

Comment: This seems to be ok , but what i cant figure out it's how can i associate the id with depID , my query will be something like SET DepartmentId = '$depId' where id =  '$id'

Comment: It worked . Thank's alot. You are right i should switch to PDO. I will  search some docs. about PDO.

Comment: Please use a prepared statement. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

`$(..).serializeArray()` will return something like

```
[
  {
    "name": "..",
    "value": "..",
  },{
    "name": "..",
    "value": "..",
  },{
    "name": "..",
    "value": "..",
  },...
]
```

But you want to group two inputs together. To do so, you can use a `for` loop that you increment by 2 after each step.

```
    var data = [],
        serialized = $('#sendObj').serializeArray(),
        i;
    for (i=0; i<serialized.length; i+=2) {
        var tmpObj = {};
        tmpObj[ serialized[i].name ] = serialized[i].value;
        tmpObj[ serialized[i+1].name ] = serialized[i+1].value;
        data.push(tmpObj);
    }
```

This should send an array to your PHP which you will need to loop

```
if (isSet($_POST['data'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['data'] as $obj) {
        //use $obj['id'] and $obj['depID']
    }
}
```

---

Although this should work, [n-dru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28945573/1557526) offers a much cleaner way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: I tried like this , but depId and id have only 1 value in all objects , the last value. and it's generating 1 object for each input so for 4 rows i have 8 Objects instead of 4.

Comment: @AndreiKap I misread your code a bit. Now it should work but as I edited in, n-dru's answer is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thank you verry much for the answer as well. I will try and save you re code also for future developments.

Answer (score 0):

$(..).serializeArray() will return something like

```
[
  {
    "name": "..",
    "value": "..",
  },{
    "name": "..",
    "value": "..",
  },{
    "name": "..",
    "value": "..",
  },...
]
```

So use this function on the PHP side, to format it back to the normal 
$_POST structure.

```
    $aPostRequest = serializedFormDatajQuery2Array(unserialize($_POST)); 

 function serializedFormDatajQuery2Array($serializedArr){
                      $aFormData = array();
                      foreach($serializedArr as $aRow){

                         if(isset($aFormData[$aRow['name']]) && !is_array($aFormData[$aRow['name']])){
                            $sValue = $aFormData[$aRow['name']];
                            $aFormData[$aRow['name']] = array();
                            $aFormData[$aRow['name']][] = $sValue;
                            $aFormData[$aRow['name']][] = $aRow['value'];
                            continue;
                         }

                                    if(is_array($aFormData[$aRow['name']])){
                                                $aFormData[$aRow['name']][] = $sValue;
                                                continue;
                                    }

                      $aFormData[$aRow['name']] = $aRow['value'];
                      }
                                 return $aFormData;
                }
```